Is the number of divergent diagrams more important than the coupling's dimension for defining the renormalizability of a theory?
It is often told as a general statement that theories with coupling constants with mass dimensions of $[g]<0$ are non-renormalizable. In general this is true. This is due to the resulting dimensionality of the vertex function which adds to the superficial degree of divergence and allows for infinitely more divergent diagrams and thus infinitely many more counter terms.
The coupling dimension and number of divergent diagrams go hand-in-hand are inseparable. But hypothetically, disregarding the specifics (dimensionality, number of derivatives, etc) of a theory:
If we had a theory with a negative coupling constant, which had subtleties in its diagram structures which allowed for convergent graphs when adding a certain amount of 3-particle vertex interactions. (I know that no theory with $[g]<0$ does this and it breaks a lot of rules. This is purely hypothetical and assuming that there is a vertex structure that exhibits a hypothetical property where additional vertices above 2 vertices don't contribute momenta factors).

Would that theory be renormalizable due to its finite number of divergent graphs, despite having $[g]<0$?

Would it be "more correct" to specifically define renormalizability as having a finite number of divergent graphs at each loop order rather than having $[g]\ge 0$?


or are there some other subtleties that I am missing for defining which theories are renormalizable?
Below is an example for depicting the hypothetical case:

and for 5+ legs and above the graphs would be finite. Hypothetically, assuming that all 2 external leg diagrams of arbitrary loop order start with a divergence of $\Lambda^4$ that can be cured with the addition of external legs with 3-particle vertices.

Hi B K. Welcome to Phys.SE. Sound like there would be divergent subdiagrams. Or could you be more explicit about the mechanism behind your hypothetical example?

Thanks for the warm welcome! I didn't have a specific mechanism in mind. I was attempting to illustrate an example of a theory with $[g]<0$ which has finite divergent diagrams at each loop by adding more vertices rather than infinitely more divergent diagrams. In context for asking which definition of non-renormalizability was more fundamental.

Another way that could illustrate such a situation would be that internal propagators contribute more powers of inverse momenta than the vertex function contributes for momenta while still having $[g]<0$ (of course, without going into subtleties like the consequences of higher derivative EoM, etc).
